# How to apply zoom-in feature for every size image of product in website sale

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, zooming

In odoo15, zoom-in feature for product are available for only image that are greater than 1024px. But I want to apply for every image size. I try to put true to "can_image_1024_be_zoomed" but zoom-in feature for this product are ugly. Not look like original feature. See below image.I also don't want to resize for the uploaded image in product form.How can I do that? Welcome for any suggestion.
[image]